# Extract up to 3 numbers from a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column starting at A2 where each row contains a name and 1 to 3 numbers in the following format:
"name : number number number"

For example:

```
Mark : some 32 text 91 here
John32 : 5/6 more text
Michael : even 32 more 21 text 3
Kyle69 : 57 something
Philip : i 2 dont 43 know
4Chris2 : 3 21 7
```

What I want is:

```
32 91
5 6
32 21 3
57
2 43
3 21 7
```

The catch is, there may or not be text in-between and around(before and/or after) the numbers and the numbers can be one or two digits(1-99)
The numbers can be extracted into one cell or respectfully 1 to 3 different cells. Extra points if it puts a " - " in the place of missing numbers (number 2 and/or number 3)

The version of Excel I'm using is 2016 and does not have formulas such as LET(), TOCOL(), NA(), FILTER(), and maybe some others so the more basic the solution is, the better.

Please and thank your for any help provided in advance!

Edit: In anyone interested, this is the mess I got to work but it only works if there are exactly 2 numbers after the " : " in the cell and returns "No. 1" or "No. 2" if either of the two numbers is outside 1-90. Why 90 and not 99? I just felt like it and getting numbers >90 is rare and should be checked so an error draws my attention better. :D

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2);"-";IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+2;1)*1));"No. 1";IF(AND(IF(VALUE(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)));IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))>0; TRUE; FALSE);IF(VALUE(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)));IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))<=90; TRUE; FALSE));IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))+1;1)*1);ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))+2;1)*1));"No. 2";IF(AND(IF(VALUE(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)));IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))>0; TRUE; FALSE);IF(VALUE(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)));IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))<=90; TRUE; FALSE));MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)));IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1))&" "&MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)));IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};FIND(":";A2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1)))+1;1)*1);2;1));"No. 2"));"No. 1")))
```

Comment: Provide 6-8 examples, and then show/describe the exact output you'd want to see based on those examples. Additionally, showing the "huge hot mess" you're already working with is helpful.

Comment: `=TRIM(CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,FIND(":",A1)+2):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)," ")))`

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic arrays started in Excel 2016, so the results of this formula should `SPILL` to the adjacent cells:

- Create an XML by

  - Replacing non-space delimiters with a space.
  - Replacing the spaces, and pre-pending/appending with xml delimiters
- Use `FILTERXML` with an appropriate xPath to extract only the numeric nodes.

```
=TRANSPOSE(
    FILTERXML(
        "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", " "), " ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
        "//s[number(.)=number(.)]"
    )
)
```

[image]

As suggested by @MayukhBhattacharya in the comments, if it is the case that MS documentation is incorrect and you do not have dynamic arrays in 2016 with SPILLing, you can enter this formula in B1, and drag across three columns then down:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/"," ")," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[number(.)=number(.)]["&COLUMNS($A:A)&"]"),"")
```

Comment: Sir, using `TRANSPOSE()` OP might need to select the no of columns, I am not sure about it, Spill may not occur in Excel 2016. Instead of using transpose they can use this as well, what do you say sir : `=IFERROR(FILTERXML(
        "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1, "/", " "), " ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
        "//s[.*0=0]["&COLUMN(A1)&"]"),"")` which needs to drag right

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Have you tested in 2016? As I wrote in my answer, and also according to Microsoft [Dynamic array formulas and spilled array behavior](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531), this feature is available in Excel 2016.

Comment: No Sir, I dont have and also i dont remember so i was asking you.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Well, I wrote it in my answer. It is possible he hasn't updated to  the latest version of 2016, in which case he should.

Comment: But Sir, i am sure about Excel 2019 where in using the formula you have given needs to hit CTRL SHIFT ENTER, and has to select the columns as well. Anyways, +1 from me.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya If it turns out that MS documentation is incorrect *(and this would not be the first time!)*, since he knows there is a maximum of three columns, he can enter it over the three columns with `ctrl-alt-enter` or request another solution.

Answer (score 0):

`=TRIM(CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,FIND(":",A1)+2):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)," ")))`

This get all characters in the string from the 2nd characters after the first found `:` to the last character. Each non-numeric character will be replaced with a space character and TRIM removes leading/trailing/duplicate space characters, leaving the numbers separated by a single space character.

In older Excel versions this requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`